# JQuery dialog set to modal but allows page interaction

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a JQuery dialog on my page that shows up with scrollbars. i tried resizing the dialog box but that did not help. I also tried resizing the div in which the dialog box is displayed but that did not work either. i also tried setting maxWidth and maxHeight, and tweaking overflow and .ui-widget-overlay - made no difference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".hlk1").click(function () {
                var linkId = $(this).attr("linkID");

                // initialize dialog
                var dlg = $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window },
                    height: 380,
                    width: 530,
                    maxHeight: 450,
                maxWidth: 600,
                open: function(){
                    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                    $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('width', '100%‌​');
                    $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('height', '100%');
                },
                close: function () {
                    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });

            // load content and open dialog
            dlg.load('page2.html?id=' + linkId).dialog('open');
        });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<a href="#" class="hlk1" linkid="305">Click here</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="hlk1" linkid="890">Click here</a>
<br/>
<div id="dialog"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me get rid of the scrollbars?

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ybqh3hpg/. Have you tried a more current version of jQuery?

Comment: are you including css for jQuery UI?. Page shown doesn't include it

Comment: You probably need to include the CSS to get the full effect of jQuery UI.

Comment: no, I did not include css. let me give it a try

Comment: I found jquery-ui.css on someone's web site but was wondering where can I download it from for a particular version of jquery-ui.js? I am using 1.11.4

Comment: @ElenaDBA: The jQuery UI website is probably a good place to download jQuery UI.  There's also the CDN: https://code.jquery.com/ui (among many other CDNs, I'm sure).

Comment: Now that I've added the css the scrollbars have appeared on the div. Resizing the dialog does not help me get rid of the scrollbars. And I never specified div size, so should not it expand with the dialog?

Comment: Also the background is still grayed out when I close out of the dialog box

Comment: Can someone post an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Is there still an issue? I see a few follow up questions, did those get addressed?

Comment: I fixed the grayed out background but the scrollbars are still there